# What does the '=' operator mean when used in an lambda expression?

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying to figure out what a line of code does but I'm struggling to understand how it works. I generally understand the purpose, use and limitations of lambda expressions in Python, but this line of code has me stumped and I couldn't find any other answers addressing it.

I'm trying to create multiple buttons for a calculator and when the button is pressed the corresponding value will appear. Rather than make 9 separate buttons, I wanted to use list comprehension to make them all at once (9 buttons, 1 for each number on the calculator). See code for more detail.

I don't really understand what `x=button_num` is doing in the `lambda x=button_num: enter_number(x)` expression and why it only works when it's written exactly this way. If I use the expression `lambda: enter_number(button_num)` instead the calculator only shows the value 9, no matter which button I press.

```
# Function inserts value into calculator based on clicked button
def enter_number(x):
    if entry_box.get() == "O":  # Used to emulate that a calculator has a "0" initially
        entry_box.delete(0, 'end')
        entry_box.insert(0, str(x))
    else:
        length = len(entry_box.get())
        entry_box.insert(length, str(x))

# Generate buttons
button_numbers = [Button(width=4, text=str(button_num), font='times 15 bold', bd=5,
                         command=lambda x=button_num: enter_number(x)) for button_num in range(10)]
```

Comment: Isn't it default function value? If `x` is not passed use the value of `button_num` as `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Giovanni's answer, the reason that the other proposed method doesn't work is that `lambda: enter_number(button_num)` will use the value of `button_num` from the enclosing scope (i.e. the list comprehension). The value of button_num then changes for each subsequent lambda, and ends on 9. Ordinarily `button_num` could be deleted at this point but since the lambda depend on it, it will stick around with its value of 9.

Default arguments, however, are evaluated at function definition time, not at function call time, so they won't fall prey to this problem. He's a more written out example

```
button_num = 0
def command(x=button_num):
    print(x)
button_num = 1
command()
```

In the above code, `command()` will print 0, not 1, since the value of `button_num` was saved when it was used as a default argument.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, ```x=button_num``` in the lambda expression is actually setting the default value and because of the property of default arguments as you mentioned the x is a new value each time the button is pressed. Thanks for the response, cleared things up for me!

Comment: This might be out of the scope of this question, but is it possible to write this in a way so that you could use a regular function without lambda?

Comment: Yes, instead of having a list comprehension you could have a for loop, and define a function inside the for loop, then create a `Button` with that function as the command, and append it to the list. You'd still need to make sure you stored the loop variable into another variable or use the default argument trick to avoid the same problems you had with lambdas though.

Answer (score 2):

`lambda` is very similar to `def`, but without the name. In both cases, something like `x=10` defines a parameter named `x` with a default value of `10`.

For example, consider this simple function.

```
def foo(x=10):
    print("x: {}".format(x))
```

When run, you will get the following results:

- `foo()` prints "x: 10"
- `foo(42)` => prints "x: 42"

`lambda` is similar to a def (not exactly, but close enough for this discussion), except that the function is anonymous - it doesn't have a name. You can then assign this function to a variable, or pass it to something that is expecting to be passed a function such as when defining a callback.

For example, this creates an anonymous function and associates it with the variable named `foo`. You can then call this exactly like you would any other function.

```
foo = lambda x=10: print("x: {}".format(x))
foo()    # prints "x: 10"
foo(42)  # prints "x: 42"
```

`lambda` is a convenient way to create a function when you don't really care what the function name is, such as when creating callbacks. By using a default parameter, you are binding the current value of a variable as the default value of the given parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very informative! Would there be a way to write the lambda expression I put in the original answer without using lambda? I tried to do it but I wasn't able to because I couldn't figure out how to make "button_num" a default parameter without using lambda. Would you need a helper function or the sort?

Comment: @ShockDoctor: in your example, there are several ways to do what you want. One is to use lambda, another is to use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial). You can also create a nested function or use a function factory. What you _can't_ do, however, is define default arguments without using one of those methods.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As in a normal function definition, you can set a default value for the input of a lambda function

```py
foo = lambda x=3: x+5
foo()
```